# Reading/writing to the WordPress database using WordPress and Javascript

Tags: wordpress

I am working with a client who is using WordPress. I am not familiar with WP like I am with other frameworks. In this situation, the client wants to allow users to enter data into a form and I will create pages to display this data so it can be managed. I am thinking I need to get the user entered data saved into a table. I will then read from this table to display in another page. I need to do CRUD stuff within WP with JavaScript.

Are there plugins that will allow me to create tables within the WP database? Can I use JavaScript to read/write to them, or do I need to use PHP? I don't have access to the source code so I am doing everything via the functions.php and JS files.

Because I don't have much experience with WP, I am not sure what can be done. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

While it's definitely doable programmatically, I don't see much reason in recreating the wheel. Perhaps Contact Form 7 would work for you. If not, Gravity Forms can do what you need, but I believe there is a cost for that.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I have Gravity Forms and wpDataTables installed now and I can see how these two interact. I am thinking I may be able to use these plugins and now have to write any additional code to read/write to/from a database. Thanks for the suggestions.